# Change text on datepickertoolbar buttons

Tags: localization, datepicker, sencha-touch

I need to localize the text on the datepickerfield buttons 'cancel' and 'done'.
I've tried [localizing in general](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?185730-Clear-Button-for-Sencha-Touch-2-DatePicker), but can't find options for these buttons.
And setting a [custom set of buttons](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?185730-Clear-Button-for-Sencha-Touch-2-DatePicker), but that only adds buttons, leaving the existing buttons there.

Anyone know how to do this?

Edit @DavidArtmann:
This is my datepickerfield, sadly your suggestion is not helping. Thanks for the option though, din't find it myself and according to the documentation it should.

```
{
    xtype: 'datepickerfield',
    name: 'policyStart',
    label: 'Polis geldig vanaf:',
    placeHolder: '',
    labelAlign: 'top',
    doneButton: 'Kies',
    cancelButton: 'Annuleer'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the docs here: [doneButton](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/touch/2.4/2.4.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.picker.Date-cfg-doneButton) and here: [cancelButton](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/touch/2.4/2.4.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.picker.Date-cfg-cancelButton) describes this very well.
You can simply give this config attribute a String, a Button Object, or false/null to hide it.

And if you want the value of an existing Datepicker Button Object, you can use the method [getCancelButton()](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/touch/2.4/2.4.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.picker.Date-method-getCancelButton) or [getDoneButton()](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/touch/2.4/2.4.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.picker.Date-method-getDoneButton), which will return a String or the Button Object or null.

EDIT:
I'm sorry, I didn't read properly. You're using a [datepickerfield](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/touch/2.4/2.4.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.field.DatePicker). Which will pop up an [datepicker](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/touch/2.4/2.4.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.picker.Date), when tapped.
**It will use its default config or your given one with [picker](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/touch/2.4/2.4.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.field.DatePicker-cfg-picker) or [setPicker()](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/touch/2.4/2.4.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.field.DatePicker-method-setPicker).**
Here you can give him a button object with the text of your choice ;)

So an example config would be:

```
{
  xtype: 'datepickerfield',
  name: 'policyStart',
  label: 'Polis geldig vanaf:',
  placeHolder: '',
  labelAlign: 'top',
  picker:  {
    xtype: 'datepicker',
    cancelButton: 'your_cancel_string',
    doneButton: 'your_done_string'
  }
}
```

*note: this is not tested*

Comment: Din't realize it was a property of the picker. Thanks, it works now.